# Invalid publish opts format when running sidecar

Tags: docker, sidecar

I want to run docker container with sidecar by [this tutorial](https://joostvdg.github.io/swe/distributed/).

For example, i have java spring boot application. Then i made such Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile for GitLab CI/CD

FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD
ARG SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE
MAINTAINER SlandShow
COPY pom.xml /build/
COPY src /build/src/
WORKDIR /build/
RUN mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=$SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE && mvn package -B -e -Dspring.profiles.active=$SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE
FROM openjdk:8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/task-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/task-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "task-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

After that i build docker image and run it:

```
$ docker build .

$ docker container run -p 8010:8010 <imageId>
```

Docker-CLI returns hash for started contaner. For example- `cc82fa748a62de634893f5594a334ada2854f0be0dff8149efb28ae67c98191c`.

Then i'am trying to start sidecar:

```
docker run -pid=container:cc82fa748a62de634893f5594a334ada2854f0be0dff8149efb28ae67c98191c -p 8080:8080 brendanburns/topz:db0fa58 /server --addr=0.0.0.0:8080
```

And get:

```
docker: invalid publish opts format (should be name=value but got '8080:8080').
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, i forgot `-` before `-p`...